Stripe checkout - embedded on flutter mobile webview
Is it possible to get Stripe checkout working on Flutter for mobile (not a web app)?
I used https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe to get the the mobile sheet variant working, but it is too limited for my needs (I need MobilePay payment method support, which is only available on web/checkout at the moment).
I haven't been able to find any good documentation on WebView with Stripe and Flutter. From what I've seen, Stripe isn't huge on WebView with checkout, but with that payment method requirement my hands are tied a bit...
I've attempted to use a webview to embed the checkout session (that works as expected on a website) but I think I may be doing it incorrectly.
Server side
Snippet of the stripe part on server side
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  ui_mode: config.checkout.embedded ? 'embedded' : 'hosted',
  expires_at: Math.floor(DateTime.now().plus({ minutes: 30 }).toSeconds()), // expire this session after 30 minutes
  locale: preferredLocale,
  line_items: [
    {
      price_data: {
        currency: quotation.currency,
        unit_amount: Math.round(quotation.amount * 100),  // amount in cents
        product_data: {
          name: config.checkout.productName,
          description: config.checkout.productDescription,
        }
      },
      quantity: 1,
    },
  ],
  mode: 'payment',
  payment_intent_data: {
    metadata,
  },
  redirect_on_completion: config.checkout.embedded ? 'never' : undefined,
  success_url: config.checkout.embedded ? undefined
    : `${config.checkout.successUrl}?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
});

Returns
  sessionId: session.id,
  clientSecret: session.client_secret ?? undefined,

Flutter frontend
Endpoint that returns stripe checkout session initial data from server & WebView controller assignment
  Future<bool> beginStripePayment() async {
    Apis apis = Apis();
    try {
      Map<String, dynamic> response = json.decode(
          await apis.createStripePaymentSession(
              widget.quoteId));
      clientSecret = response["clientSecret"];
      checkoutUrl = 'https://checkout.stripe.com/pay/$clientSecret';
      debugPrint(checkoutUrl);
      controller = WebViewController()
        ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
        ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(checkoutUrl));
      return Future.value(true);
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
    return Future.value(false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<bool>(
      future: pageInitialization,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.data == true) {
          return SizedBox(
              height: commonFunctions.getTotalHeightDividedByPassedValue(
                  context, 2),
              width:
                  commonFunctions.getTotalWidthDividedByPassedValue(context, 2),
              child: WebViewWidget(
                controller: controller,
                gestureRecognizers: Set()
                  ..add(Factory(() => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer())),
              ));
        } else {
          return Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: centeredLoadingIndicator(context,
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }

I get a "Something went wrong - The page you were looking for could not be found. Please check the URL or contact the merchant."
Is the problem URL or secret key/publishable key related? Or is there other steps required to get the checkout session functional through a Webview? The web variant uses a custom Stripe UI elements to generate the url, I'm hoping we don't need something like that.

I don't think you are using the correct URL to render a Stripe checkout page in your application. You should use the url from the Checkout Session object to render the page.

Thanks, for that.
I actually forgot to update the snippet I sent you, but I had already corrected my url to "https://checkout.stripe.com/c/pay/$clientSecret".
I still get the error. I think it's something else...(I have managed to get the same setup working with stripe.paymentLinks.create({... but that comes with some other issues I'd have to address if I went that way.

That's not how it works though, you don't manually build the checkout.stripe.com link youself(are you reading some docs that say that?) . Instead there's a url field on the object returned from the API and that's what you use.
